# Are there any public-key encryption schemes based on DLog?

Tags: public-key, discrete-logarithm, one-way-function, hardness-assumptions, trapdoor

There are public-key encryption schemes based on many different mathematical hardness assumptions, like the hardness of Decisional Diffie-Hellman problem, the hardness of the Factoring problem, the hardness of the RSA problem, etc.

But my question is, are there any public-key encryption schemes based on the hardness of the Discrete Log problem?  Does the hardness of the Discrete Log problem even imply the existence of secure public-key encryption?

Comment: Elgamal encryption.

Comment: @kelalaka El Gamal is based on the hardness of the Decisional Diffie-Hellman (DDH) problem, which is a stronger hardness assumption than the hardness of the Discrete Log (DLog) problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a major open research question whether such a scheme exists, and how to construct one (see, for example, [Open Problem 9.10](https://courses.grainger.illinois.edu/CS498AC3/fa2020/Files/Lecture_9_Scribe.pdf)). Of course, we do have schemes like (hashed) ElGamal, which are based on the conjectured hardness of the (computational or decisional) Diffie-Hellman problem. But it is unknown whether either of these problems is equivalent to the discrete logarithm problem (except, of course, in groups where discrete log is easy).

Comment: Can you give some kind of proof that it’s an open problem, like a citation?  And is the open problem merely about finding such a construction, or is it about whether the hardness of DLog implies the existence of secure public-key encryption?

Comment: See my updated answer.